# Playwright testing failed to fetch on Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, jestjs, fetch, playwright

I encountered a bug with fetch inside page.evaluate. Initially, I thought it was blocked by the browser, I then set the bypassCSP and ignoreHTTPS to true but the issue still remained. I wonder if there is any fix for this? The test can run successfully on local but for some reason it is always failed to run on pipeline.

```
private async seedBackups() {
    await page.evaluate(async (apiURL) => {
        const file = new File(["backup"], "userBackup.json", {
            type: "application/json",
        });

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("userBackup", file);

        const createBackupResponse = await fetch(`${apiURL}/api/v1/backups`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        });

        return await createBackupResponse.json();
    }, this.apiURL);
}
```

Error: page.evaluate: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to fetchError

- Playwright Version: 1.9
- Operating System: Window
- Node.js version: 10.12
- Browser: Chromium

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: THe only information It logged is: Error: page.evaluate: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Failed to fetchError.

Comment: Where are you getting that `apiURL` from?

Comment: Which agent are you using? Please try to use a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and check if you still have this issue.